# textpos and tcolorbox incompatibility

Tags: tcolorbox, textpos

I am using the two packages:

- `textpos`, for positioning text using absolute coordinates
- `tcolorbox`, for a better graphical representation of the content

There seems to be an incompatibility between the two. I would like, for example, to make a `tcolorbox` with the only left border.

This is fine:

```
\begin{tcolorbox}[height=8cm,boxrule=0mm,leftrule=2mm]
text
\end{tcolorbox}
```

When the `tcolorbox` is put inside of a `textblock`, it gives an error:

```
\begin{textblock*}{20cm}(\boxStartX,\boxStartY)
\begin{tcolorbox}[height=8cm,boxrule=0mm,leftrule=2mm]
text
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{textblock*}
```

The error is:

```
Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted). [\end{textblock*}]
```

The error stays if I change the unit of measure to `pt`.

There are no issues if I use the `tcolorbox` without modifying its border width.

Do you happen to have any suggestions?

Comment: Please make your code complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand.

Comment: `tcolorbox` is built on top of `tikz`, and with `tikz` you can position text (or anything else) anywhere on the page using the page node; but it might perhaps be a little bit too powerful (the manual is 1000+ pages). What do you intend to do? There may be much simpler solutions and packages available.